# Search the page with string “abc” and print search result in log in cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation

On this URL I need to Search the page with the string “abc” and print out the search result in log in cypress can anyone suggest how to do it?
http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/webtables/

```
import {BasePage} from '../page-objects/base-page';
import {HomePage} from '../page-objects/home-page';

describe('Search text and print in Log', () => {
  const basePage = new BasePage();
  const homePage = new HomePage();

  it('Launch Way2', () => {
    basePage.navigate();
  });

  it('Search the page with string “xyz” and print out the search result in log', () => {
    const log = Cypress.log(homePage.serachTest());
    const l = Cypress.log(cy.get('body'));
    const t = Cypress.log(cy.get('[ng-controller=mainCtrl]'));
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html) and loop through the all the `td` and search for the element. Something like:

```
cy.get('[ng-repeat="column in columns"]').each(($ele, i) => {
    if ($ele.text === 'xyz') {
        cy.log('Search Successful for ' + ($ele.text))
    }
})
```

Comment: Why I am not able to find the element with the conventional method, is it because of iframe?

Comment: When I am inspecting the element in a table cannot inspect that particular field rather everything is in the body just want to understand the reason.